# PHP Copying Data between 2 Tables not Merging

Tags: php

I have 2 tables in MySQL.

Table1 holds fresh records all the time so it gets Truncated before new records are added.

Table2 hold a history of all the records Table1 has had so I copy records from Table1 to Table2 and then Truncate Table1 and add fresh data.

My problem is that Table2 doesn't see to accumulate records...it always holds the same amount of records that Table1 has before Truncating.

I'm using this code:

```
$backuphistory=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `Table2` SELECT * FROM `Table1`");
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: http://il1.php.net/mysqli_error

Comment: Did you try specifying the field names for table2 ?

Comment: Yes I tried specifying the field names but got the same result

Comment: i think mysqli don't execute the sql second time if you have primary key and you truncate table 1 then it will stop for duplicate entry .. i suggest to obserbe the query in your query panel on that two table by inserting with same primary key